# Average instead of Sum in Grand Total of Pivot Table in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, is there any way that the "Grand Total" of a column in a Pivot Table is something different than the values of the column represents? (for instance, in a sum column, show the average).

An example would be in a sheet with daily sales of several products. You want in the column for each product to show the yearly sales (sum column), but the grand total to show the average of the values in the column.

[image]

This is very easy to do in Excel, since you can configure the Grand Total to be other function. I have not been able to find the same functionality in Google Sheets.

Edit: Original question was badly formulated.

Comment: In the report editor, theres a dropdown to change what 'summazise' .  I found a video that demonstrates this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=frf8NFeqH7Q  . Normally, a link isnt the best to add in here, but this is a complex description and depends on your piviot table. Also, not totally sure it helps in your case.

Answer (score 4):

Though it reads `Grand Total`, the presented result depends on the choices you make on `Summarise by` as clearly seen in the image.

In our example for `Days` the `Grand Total` is the **average of all days**.
For `Points` the `Grand Total` is the **minimum of all points**

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think my initial question was badly formulated. What I wanted to know is if the Grand Total could be something different than for the column. I'll edit the original question.